# close and 'save as' for 100 of MS Paint files at once?

Tags: javascript, powershell, command-line-interface, batch-processing, paint

I take everyday 100 print screen images and paste them on another 100 MS paint files. I need to automate the process of saving all 100 opened files at once. I know that using 'tasklist | find "mspaint"' will bring all tasks with process IDs but how can I add more steps to make it all saved at once? e.g. 1.png, 2.png...100.png.

Comment: 1) Nor Powershell neither javascript will help you with that, because powershell way is hard to communicate with non-.Net windows (like paint)

Comment: 2) Why you do this? There are tons of software that save screenshot to file when you hit `PrnScr`.

Comment: Describe what exactly you do and why, maybe we are able to solve this problem different way.

Comment: @filimonic If you use Windows + PrtScr, it creates an image in Pictures/Screenshots folder

Comment: XnView has automation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to this post https://www.timsblog.nl/2016/01/13/asynchronously-save-images-in-the-clipboard-to-file/, I finally find a perfect answer to my question. the whole process can be fully automated using powershell_ise.

```
Register-EngineEvent -SourceIdentifier PowerShell.OnIdle -Action {
    $content = Get-Clipboard -Format Image
    If ($content) 
    {
        $path = $psISE.CurrentFile.FullPath | Split-Path
        $filename = "$path\ImageCap - " + (Get-date -Format 'hh-mm-ss') + '.png'
        $content.Save($filename,'png')
        Set-Clipboard -Value $Null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Forget about `mspaint` completely - use Windows PowerShell's `Get-ClipBoard` command to obtain the screenshot and write it to disk programmatically:

```
<# use PrintScreen or Snipping Tool to capture the screen and copy to clipboard as normal #>

# then grab from clipboard
$screenshot = Get-Clipboard -Format Image

# then save to disk
$screenshot.Save("C:\path\to\screenshot.png", [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)

# and free it from memory
$screenshot.Dispose()
```

Comment: Nice deal.  Could skip the assigning and freeing of the variable as well and have a one-liner `(Get-Clipboard -Format Image).Save("C:\path\to\screenshot.png", [System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat]::Png)`